# Maintaining an Ordered collection of objects

Tags: c++, collections, dynamic, html-lists

I have the following requirements for a collection of objects:

- Dynamic size (in theory unlimited, but in practice a couple of thousand should be more than enough)
- Ordered, but allowing reorder and insertion at arbitrary locations.
- Allows for deletion
- Indexed Access - Random Access
- Count

The objects I am storing are not large, a couple of properties and a small array or two (256 booleans)

Is there any built in classes I should know about before I go writing a linked list?

Comment: How large is the type of object you are going to store in the container?  Is it expensive to copy?  How frequently are elements inserted or removed from the middle of the container?  Do you need random access to individual elements?  Have you looked at any of the STL containers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Original answer: That sounds like `std::list` (a doubly linked list) from the Standard Library.

New answer:
After your change to the specs, a `std::vector` might work as long as there aren't more than a few thousand elements and not a huge number of insertions and deletions in the middle of the vector.  The linear complexity of insertion and deletion in the middle may be outweighed by the low constants on the vector operations.  If you are doing a lot of insertions and deletions just at the beginning and end, `std::deque` might work as well.

Comment: I see he's changed it on you.  He's added Random Access which invalidates list as an acceptable option.

Comment: @wheaties: Thanks for the note -- I just updated my answer.  A linked list wouldn't work for fast random access, even though the question still mentions writing one.  Of course, it all depends on the ratio of random accesses to updates.

Comment: Sorry about the change of spec - a comment made me realise i needed a few more things. Thanks for the updated answer, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified enough of your requirements to select the best container.

> Dynamic size (in theory unlimited, but in practice a couple of thousand should be more than enough)

STL containers are designed to grow as needed.

> Ordered, but allowing reorder and insertion at arbitrary locations.

Allowing reorder?  A std::map can't be reordered: you can delete from one std::map and insert into another using a different ordering, but as different template instantiations the two variables will have different types.  std::list has a `sort()` member function [thanks Blastfurnace for pointing this out], particularly efficient for large objects.  A std::vector can be resorted easily using the non-member `std::sort()` function, particularly efficient for tiny objects.

Efficient insertion at arbitrary locations can be done in a map or list, but how will you find those locations?  In a list, searching is linear (you must start from somewhere you already know about and scan forwards or backwards element by element).  std::map provides efficient searching, as does an already-sorted vector, but inserting into a vector involves shifting (copying) all the subsequent elements to make space: that's a costly operation in the scheme of things.

> Allows for deletion

All containers allow for deletion, but you have the exact-same efficiency issues as you do for insertion (i.e. fast for list if you already know the location, fast for map, deletion in vectors is slow, though you can "mark" elements deleted without removing them, e.g. making a string empty, having a boolean flag in a struct).

> Indexed Access - Random Access

vector is indexed numerically (but can be binary searched), map by an arbitrary key (but no numerical index).  list is not indexed and must be searched linearly from a known element.

> Count

`std::list` provides an O(n) `size()` function (so that it can provide O(1) splice), but you can easily track the size yourself (assuming you won't splice).  Other STL containers already have O(1) time for `size()`.

*Conclusions*

Consider whether using a std::list will result in lots of inefficient linear searches for the element you need.  If not, then a list does give you efficient insertion and deletion.  Resorting is good.

A map or hash map will allow quick lookup and easy insertion/deletion, can't be resorted, but you can easily move the data out to another map with another sort criteria (with moderate efficiency.

A vector allows fast searching and in-place resorting, but the worst insert/deletion.  It's the fastest for random-access lookup using the element index.

Comment: why would you say that a vector can be more easily reordered than a list?

Comment: To use std::sort you need a random access iterator, hence want a vector<> rather than a list<>

Comment: You could use a map<>, but as Tony notes a re-order cannot be done directly. However, you could just create a new map type for the new ordering and construct it from the hold one. Given the more efficient deletion operation, it might give an edge over vector.

Comment: @etarion: Keith gave the same reason I would have.

@Keith: re maps... glad you agree, though it's a bit of a hassle as you'd probably end up wanting some run-time selection of the active map, as in `enum { BY_NAME, BY_AGE, BY_ADDRESS } Order; Order order; ... switch(order) { case BY_NAME: map_by_name.some_operation; break; ...`.  You could consolidate that indirection in an interface class so higher level application logic doesn't deal with it constantly, but anyone asking this question's unlikely to be comfortable with the programming involved.

Comment: std::list can be reordered. It has a sort() member function.

Comment: @Keith, @Tony: See Blastfurnace - the structure of a list makes it more suited for reordering a sequence, really, as you just have to change the "links" and don't have to move the objects itselves around.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, @etarion: yeah - great point, especially for large objects. Will update this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

-Insertion and Deletion: This is possible for any STL container, but the question is how long it takes to do it. Any linked-list container (list, map, set) will do this in constant time, while array-like containers (vector) will do it in linear time (with constant-amortized allocation).

-Sorting: Considering that you can keep a sorted collection at all times, this isn't much of an issue, any STL container will allow that. For map and set, you don't have to do anything, they already take care of keeping the collection sorted at all times. For vector or list, you have to do that work, i.e. you have to do binary search for the place where the new elements go and insert them there (but STL Algorithms has all the pieces you need for that).

-Resorting: If you need to take the current collection you have sorted with respect to rule A, and resort the collection with respect to rule B, this might be a problem. Containers like map and set are parametrized (as a type) by the sorting rule, this means that to resort it, you would have to extract every element from the original collection and insert them in a new collection with a new sorting rule. However, if you use a vector container, you can just use the STL sort function anytime to resort with whatever rule you like.

-Random Access: You said you needed random access. Personally, my definition of random access means that any element in the collection can be accessed (by index) in constant time. With that definition (which I think is quite standard), any linked-list implementation does not qualify and it leaves you with the only option of using an array-like container (e.g. std::vector).

Conclusion, to have all those properties, it would probably be best to use a std::vector and implement your own sorted insertion and sorted deletion (performing binary search into the vector to find the element to delete or the place to insert the new element). If your objects that you need to store are of significant size, and the data according to which they are sorted (name, ID, etc.) is small, you might consider splitting the problem by holding a unsorted linked-list of objects (with full information) and keeping a sorted vector of keys along with a pointer to the corresponding node in the linked-list (in that case, of course, use std::list for the former, and std::vector for the latter).

BTW, I'm no grand expert with STL containers, so I might have been wrong in the above, just think for yourself. Explore the STL for yourself, I'm sure you will find what you need, or at least all the pieces that you need. Maybe, look at Boost libraries too.

Comment: `map` and `set` cannot be implemented using a linked list, they are (almost always) implemented as a self-balancing binary search tree like a Red-Black tree.  So, the complexity for insertion and removal for those containers is logarithmic, not constant.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out! I always kinda wondered exactly how map and set were implemented, but never really investigated it.

Comment: The typical implementation is a red-black tree, but the standard does not mandate it. @James McNellis: actually one could see a SkipList as an extension over the traditional linked list, and it qualifies for `map` and `set` implementations, though I've never seen any in practice.